# rabbitmq-server fails to start

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I installed RabbitMQ and it was working fine. Then, once my system memory is full and it stopped working. I cleared the system memory and again started the RabbitMQ and it didnt get started. Below is the status which i get.

```
root@qa-development-vm:/usr/# systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2018-12-06 06:13:31 UTC; 641ms ago
  Process: 32243 ExecStop=/bin/sh -c while ps -p $MAINPID >/dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1; done (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 32105 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 32253 (beam.smp)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─32253 /usr/lib/erlang/erts-10.1.3/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -zdbbl 128000 -K true -- -root /usr/lib/erlang -progname erl -- -home ...
           └─32465 erl_child_setup 1024

root@qa-development-vm:/usr/# journalctl -xn
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-12-06 05:00:15 UTC, end at Thu 2018-12-06 06:13:46 UTC. --
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: * connected to epmd (port 4369) on qa-development-vm
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: no other nodes on qa-development-vm
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: * suggestion: start the node
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: current node details:
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-90@qa-development-vm'
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm rabbitmqctl[400]: - cookie hash: mF/Qt8msGSizqNbONVAZQw==
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
-- Subject: Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit rabbitmq-server.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Dec 06 06:13:46 qa-development-vm systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
```

I tired [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1596043) but nothing happens for me.I checked log also but nothing was there. I dropped all the logs and again try to start the server but getting the same error and no log files are generated.

I reinstalled it and its working again. but i wants the reason of it and how to solve it, if happens again.

Comment: When you say "system memory is full" do you mean your disk had filled up?

Comment: yes, hard disk was full @LukeBakken

Answer (score 5):

The solution in the linked document is an option if large message stores are what is filling your disk. Note that this will cause message loss as well as loss of system configuration:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/*
systemctl start rabbitmq-server
```

There isn't enough information provided ("nothing happens for me" isn't helpful) to diagnose further. Re-installation may have correctly deleted the system configuration, but a full re-installation should not be necessary to fix this issue.